# Django Sorl Thumbnail Resizing error

Tags: django

I"m been using django sorl thumbnail and I encountered an problem.

I set the settings on the template to scale any image that is larger than 500 width and height to be resize to around 500 width and height.
The problem is , What happen if an image is lower than the fixed settings which is  height and width 500.The image is then scaled up to 500 width and height .
How can fix this problem so any image that is lower than 500 width and height does not need to be resize.

```
{ % thumbnail item.image "x500" as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}">
 {% endthumbnail %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solved it, you have to set `upscale=False`.

[Upscale](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html#upscale) is a boolean and controls if the image can be upscaled or not, whose default value is `True`.

```
{% thumbnail item.image "x500" upscale=False as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Then your images lower than 500px will not be upscaled.